# Hebrew characters from SQL don't show up correctly ( PHP )

Tags: php, sql, hebrew

this is a long known problem which i've solved on several projects but this time
nothing seems to help.
As i play with it the hebrew chars sometimes show up as question marks (???? ????)
and sometimes as plain Gibrish (nonsense).

All my tables are set to Utf-8, as in my meta.
I have tried running :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'hebrew' ")
```

and

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8' ")
```

trying setting header with php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But Nothing seems to help.
Any clue what i should do?

**EDIT **
Well, thanks to Bekka's answer, the problem was the correct syntax is UTF8 not UTF-8.

Comment: The correct syntax for `SET NAMES` is `SET NAMES utf8;` - make sure you catch and display mySQL errors. Other than that, consider adding more detail about what you are doing with the data, possibly show some code

Comment: sometimes i just hate myself. Thank you Pekka that was the problem. works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in your syntax. Try the following instead:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

Though I would advise you to learn a different database engine, such as **[PDO](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**